# Cross apply / Joining two column when left column does not appear with right column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, ssms, cross-apply

Imagining I have the following table:

[image: Food served per month]

We can see that Tuna was not served in Month 1.
I would like to make it appear also in Month 1.

[image: Food server per month goal]

How can I achieve this?

Thank you !

Comment: What have you tried so far to achieve this? Please post your attempts first. I *assume* you have a table of food types, and a table of months?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `cross apply` to give each food every month. That seems to be what you want.

```
declare @table table (Food varchar(16), [Month] int)
insert into @table
values
('Pizza',1),
('Burgers',1),
('Salad',1),
('Tuna',2),
('Pizza',2),
('Burgers',2),
('Salad',2)

select distinct
    f.Food
    ,m.Month
from @table f
cross apply (select distinct [Month] from @table) m
order by m.Month
```

To find out what months `Tuna` was not served in...

```
select distinct [MONTH]
from @table
where [Month] not in (select [Month] from @table where Food = 'Tuna')
```

Comment: Thanks this does the job, will accept it. Also the others but you were first.
One question, what query could I use if I wanted to check for example which months tuna was not served? Could you add to your answer please ?

Comment: done @LuisDoCantoBrum but usually new questions should be asked in a new thread so they gain visibility. Since this one was simple I added it

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use two subqueries with `DISTINCT` and `CROSS JOIN`

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Food FROM T) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [Month] FROM T) t2
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a5d334f3bbf82eb6d985cf53b249460d)

Comment: Nice, similar approach

Comment: Thanks for the help. I gave the 1st reply the correct answer

Comment: I consider this the better answer.  First, it directly gets all combinations of food and month quite clearly.  Second, by limiting the distinct to the subqueries -- rather than on the entire results -- it should be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the issue is that you have a table without the record of the month for some type of food.
For me the best way its to create a table "month_of_year" that will contains only the number from 1 to 12.

then:

select distinct Food
   into #tmp
   from your_table

select a.Food, month_of_year.month
   from #tmp a cross join month_of_year

drop table #tmp

then if you want for example see the total of food for the year, go in left from the last table that I have written with the table of the sum, and you will have all the food/month with the total and in case a null on the total where the food was not be served

If you need more information ask =)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I gave the 1st reply the correct answer